# Does the wifi extender work with poor signal?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I have read some articles about [wifi extenders](https://www.repeaterstore.com/pages/wifi-booster-repeater-extender-differences). I do not understand if it makes sense in a place where the signal is already poor (-70 dBm). Does the wifi extender have more sensitive receiver than notebook?

Comment: ? Of course you would place it in a location that still has adequate reception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extender may have a better receptor than your PC, but it cannot recover a too-poor signal. Even if it can, this will cause errors that will slow-down the transmission
speed by causing resends.

The extender should be placed between the emitter and the receiving device,
in a place where the reception is good, so as to receive and then resend the signal,
thus in effect extending the range of the emitter (wherefore its name).

Comment: What dBm signal is sufficient? I do not understand the wifi signal strength. When I sit one meter from the router with clear view the signal ranges between -38 to -55 dBm according to Wifi analyzer on Android Nokia  phone.

Comment: This is close to the maximum. See [this article](https://eyesaas.com/wi-fi-signal-strength/) for more info. Starting from above 67 dBm is considered as not a strong signal, and at 80 dBm this is unreliable.

Comment: I have read this document already. I do not understand why the signal varies. Why it  does not stay at minus thirties level all the time but degrades under -50 dBm.

Comment: You might have interference from other sources, even electrical equipment.